# Flip image to reveal back iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Basic newbie question.

I am looking to place several images into a collection view. How can I have the image flip over to reveal the back of the image in Xcode using swift? Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by flipping the image to reveal the back of it. Are you talking about a horizontal flip transition?

Comment: check out this project from git hub this could help you. http://advanceioscode.blogspot.com/2015/11/colour-memory-44-grid-project.html

Comment: Thank you for the link to the project. This is exactly what I was looking for. Again thanks of the help. I look forward to contributing to the community soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about what exactly are you trying to achieve, but I'm using this function to rotate image horizontally and to change the image during the transition. Hope it helps.

```
private func flipImageView(imageView: UIImageView, toImage: UIImage, duration: NSTimeInterval, delay: NSTimeInterval = 0)
{
    let t = duration / 2

    UIView.animateWithDuration(t, delay: delay, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in

        // Rotate view by 90 degrees
        let p = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90)), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        imageView.layer.transform = p

    }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in

        // New image
        imageView.image = toImage

        // Rotate view to initial position
        // We have to start from 270 degrees otherwise the image will be flipped (mirrored) around Y axis
        let p = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(270)), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        imageView.layer.transform = p

        UIView.animateWithDuration(t, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in

            // Back to initial position
            let p = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(0)), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            imageView.layer.transform = p

        }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
        })
    })
}
```

Don't forget to import GLKit.

Comment: Thanks of the guidance. I will also give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

```
 -(void)showButtton  
 {  
 self.userInteractionEnabled = false;  
 [UIView transitionWithView:self duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{  
 //code to change the image of UIButton  
 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {  
 self.userInteractionEnabled = true;  
 }];  
 }
```

Here is a [code](http://advanceioscode.blogspot.com/) to do so.